# Does anyone out there have an old textbook about learning Moiyen Hakka?

Tags: learning, hakka

I was born in Montreal and my parents are both Hakka from Calcutta.  They never taught me the language and now in my thirties, I'm realizing how important it is to me to go back to my roots.  I want to learn my mother tongue!

Would anyone out there have any good resources, recordings, textbooks, etc. that would help me learn the basics?  I have already seen Eric Chen's Youtube lessons, which are great, but unfortunately, quite limited.

Comment: Though I am not from that part of China, I advise you to listen to a podcast called *the China history podcast*, which talks about Hakka people as well as generic China history. This may not be directly related to your question, but I would be glad if it is still helpful.

Comment: Definitely helpful :) . I'll check it out!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a book entitled [*Dialect  and  Folkways  Handbook  in  Meizhou*](https://www.amazon.cn/dp/B00WLKE0SA/ref=sr_1_1?__mk_zh_CN=%E4%BA%9A%E9%A9%AC%E9%80%8A%E7%BD%91%E7%AB%99&keywords=%E6%A2%85%E5%B7%9E%E6%96%B9%E8%A8%80%E6%B0%91%E4%BF%97%E5%9B%BE%E5%85%B8&qid=1557286475&s=gateway&sr=8-1) (梅州方言民俗图典) that you can purchase but it is probably more like a dictionary than anything else.

Resources for, specifically, Moiyen (梅州) Hakka are going to be far more scarce than for a broader topic like the Hakka language in general.

Searching for Meixian (梅縣) Hakka would even greatly increase the number of results you get.

- 现代汉语方言音库・梅县话音档
- 梅县客家方言志
- 梅县方言词典

Answer (score 1):

With any of the Chinese topolects, having a good foundation in standard Mandarin will open up a lot more resources.

The other thing with the Hakkasphere is that it is a lot more fragmented (considering the person to distance covered ratio of the diaspora), compared to e.g. the Cantonese speaking world or even the Hokkien/Hoklo/Minnan world. Although you specifically want Moiyen/Meixian Hakka, I'd also consider [Sixian Hakka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixian_dialect), which is the Taiwan version of the Moiyen "side".

Online though, we have a substantial amount of resources.

- a dictionary of [Hakka expressions](https://hakka.dict.edu.tw//hakkadict/index.htm)
- the official [Ministry of Education on Taiwan dictionary](https://www.moedict.tw/)
- courses of Memrise "[Decks](https://decks.memrise.com/courses/english/?q=Hakka)"
- two official Glossika courses ([Sixian](https://ai.glossika.com/language/learn-hakka-sixian) and Hailu)

THere's even Taiwan's [Hakka TV](http://www.hakkatv.org.tw/), as well as a wealth of [religious](https://www.jw.org/hak/) [literature](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/?contentLanguageFilter=hak_id) (including the [Bible with audio](https://live.bible.is/bible/HAKTHV/MAT/1)), and a large collection of Hakka opera (漢劇), including [classic tales](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5EWttBN16h4).